# Почему при выборе первого пункта option не срабатывает функция on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему при выборе первого пункта option не срабатывает функция on change? Как сделать, чтобы при повторном выборе первого пункта функция все-равно срабатывала?

```js
$(document).on( "change", 'select', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
    $('.result').append('<b>'+value+'</b>');
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 260px;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select>
  <option value="Выбор 1">Выбор 1</option>
  <option value="Выбор 2">Выбор 2</option>
  <option value="Выбор 3">Выбор 3</option>
  <option value="Выбор 4">Выбор 4</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Потому что он уже выбран? оО

Comment: @Даня а как сделать, чтобы при повторном выборе также срабатывала функция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему при выборе первого пункта option не срабатывает функция on change?

Оно срабатывает только при изменении значения.

Вот таким образом можно эмулировать выбор. Или добавить пустой `option`... Тогда все будет работать и так.

```js
$(document).on("change", 'select', test);
$('select').each((_, o) => {
  console.log(o)
  test.call(o)
})

function test() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.result').append('<b>' + value + '</b>');
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 260px;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select>
  <option value="Выбор 1">Выбор 1</option>
  <option value="Выбор 2">Выбор 2</option>
  <option value="Выбор 3">Выбор 3</option>
  <option value="Выбор 4">Выбор 4</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а почему для динамически добавленного select не применяется возможность выполнения функции по клику на первый пункт? Добавил указанный в select HTML через $().html('')

Comment: @Alex, для динамической работы нужно менять стратегию работы скриптов... Добавил `select` - добавь и его первый `option` в соответствующий `result`.